# Removing img and p tags from HTML

Tags: php, html, string

I have following HTML code snippet:

```
<li>2011-10-17</li>
<li><p><img style="float: left;" alt="photo1" src="/images/stories/site/news/photo1.jpg" height="148" width="217">Some text</p>...
</li>
<li>
<a href=" index.php?option="com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=9&quot;" title="">
     Read more
</a>    

</li>
```

I need to remove `<img>` and `<p>` tags. I tried to use strip_tags, some regexp
combinations, but still no good.

Any ideas about removing this from string ?

Comment: What do you need the output to look like? Do you need to remove just the tag, or everything within as well?

Comment: Do you need to remove the tags, or the tags and their inner contents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already tried `strip_tags()`, but perhaps didn't use the allowable tags parameter:

```
strip_tags($your_html, "<a><li><ul><ol>");
```

Add additional allowed tags to the string, if necessary.